# Setting expiration in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have to set expiration for my static files of my application in IIS 7. Using the dialog below: I set it to 10 days.

[image]

But when I look at my page analysis using PageSpeed add-on in Chrome, I see that there is no expiration on the files.

[image]

Do I have to do something in my application configuration too?

Comment: this belongs on serverfault

Comment: Yes, you were right. I found my answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/452221/setting-expiration-in-iis-7 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pure in your web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- Cache Settings -->
  <location path="data">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00"/>
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

For the path value, you can do something like : images\interface *(example)*
For the cacheControlMaxAge : 10 = days = DD.HH:MM:SS

Comment: I add the part you suggested but nothing changes. It says "expiration not specified" for the two .js files in my Data folder.

Comment: Did you restart your IIS and the application pool?